# How to get Network Status to run with Parity?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, explorers

I am trying to use this - https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Network-Status

I get that installed and it seems to run but nothing shows in localhost. I get this nothing in the http://localhost:3000 display. The cli output is shown below. What is the cause and how should I correct it?

Applying action restartProcessId on app [node-app](ids: 0)
[PM2] node-app ✓
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user        │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ node-app │ 0  │ fork │ 23492 │ online │ 9       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 13.4 MB   │ satoshimaca │ disabled

I also get the logs working and the connection is established so the present issue is accessing the logs via a UI, eg http://localhost:3000

Here are the logs -

> 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =i= Starting web3
>   connection 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =✓= Web3
>   connection established 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] ==>
>   Getting info 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =i= { name:
>   'parity0', 0|node-app |   contact: 'Trevor', 0|node-app |   coinbase:
>   '0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e', 0|node-app |   node:
>   'Parity//v1.11.1-beta-6654d02-20180515/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.25.0',
>   0|node-app |   net: '8995', 0|node-app |   protocol: 63, 0|node-app | 
>   api: '0.15.3', 0|node-app |   port: '30300', 0|node-app |   os:
>   'linux', 0|node-app |   os_v: '4.13.0-1017-gcp', 0|node-app |
>   client: '0.1.1', 0|node-app |   canUpdateHistory: true } 0|node-app |
>   2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [wsc] =i= Starting socket connection
>   0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =✓= Installed chain filter
>   0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =✓= Installed pending
>   filter 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [wsc] =i= The socket
>   connection has been opened. 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00:
>   [eth]     Trying to login 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [wsc]
>   =✓= The socket connection has been established. 0|node-app | 2018-05-29 09:26 +00:00: [eth] =i= { id: 'parity0', 0|node-app |
>   stats:  0|node-app |    { active: true, 0|node-app |      syncing:
>   false, 0|node-app |      mining: false, 0|node-app |      hashrate: 0,
>   0|node-app |      peers: 1, 0|node-app |      gasPrice: '0',
>   0|node-app |      uptime: 100 } }

Answer (score 1):

This works with eth-netstats I found. If you use

1. npm start in eth-netstats the eth-net-intelligence-api product does run.